# how to define login user and become root in playbook

Tags: ansible

my loginuser is user1 and i want to execute the playbook with root. how can i do this. if i use in cmdline it does not work like this

```
ansible-playbook main.yaml -i hosts --user=git -k --become-user=root --ask-become-pass --become-method=su
```

Please tell me how to implement this.

```yaml
name: Install and Configure IEM
hosts: rhel
ansible_become: yes
ansible_become_method: su
ansible_become_user: root
ansible_become_pass: passw0rd
tasks:
 
 - name: Creating masthead file path
   file: path=/etc/opt/BESClient state=directory
   
 - name: Creating install directory
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, please be a bit more specific when asking question: what have you tried, what do you expect, etc. See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 28):

I use :

**deploy.yml**

```
- name: Todo something
  hosts: all
  become: yes
  become_user: root
  become_method: su
```

When you execute the playbook pass the password as an extra var.

```
 --extra-vars='ansible_become_pass=password'
```

Comment: You're _much_ better off using the `--ask-become-pass` flag, rather than passing the password through `--extra-vars`, as passing it through `--extra-vars` will store your password in your history (i.e. `~/.bash_history` in bash).

Comment: You can store your password in a vault for security

Comment: You can also use an ssh key pair thanks to the variable `ansible_ssh_private_key_file`

Answer (score 5):

From [Ansible docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html):

- you can set those in the playbook as @Raul-Hugo, with `become_user` and `become_user`;
- alternatively, it can also be done in the inventory, which allows setting per host or group. But then the variables get "ansible_" prefix: `ansible_become_user`, `ansible_become_user`, etc. That's why the playbook you gave in your question did not work: it used variable names that are used in the inventory.

Answer (score 1):

## You can become root like below and install the packages

```
tasks:
    - name: install apache package
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      yum:
        name: httpd
        state: present

    - name: ensure apache is running
      become: yes
      become_user: root
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: started
```

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers caused Ansible to try to login *as* root from the beginning. but in this case, the user you request is `git` so the below example worked for me:

```
- name: Install and Configure IEM
  hosts: rhel
  tasks:
   - name: Creating masthead file path  
     file: path=/etc/opt/BESClient state=directory
     remote_user: git
     become: yes    # when not specifying `become_user` it's "root"
```

This will cause it to login as `git` and after the login - switch to `root`